# Resize font in TextBox in Grid

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, font-size

My question below is answered but I just realised that now the `FontSize` only resizes in one direction.

Is there a possibility to bind two paths? Or another option?

Previous question
I have a `Grid` [20,20] with `TextBox`es in it. In these `TextBoxe`s I put numbers. When the application starts up it's fullscreen. If I resize the window the `Grid` with the `TexBox`es also resizes. But the `Font` stays the same. So I want to change the `FontSize` when the Window resizes. I tried:

```
 FontSize="{Binding ElementName=aTextBox, Path=Height}"
```

between the `TextBox` tags. But that doesn't work. A binding with the `Grid` or `Window` with property `Height` or `Width` didn't work either. With binding to a slider the `FontSize` changes according to the the value of the slider. Does anybody have a nice solution?

Answer (score 4):

The `Height` property is the initial height of the `TextBox`. The `ActualHeight` represents the height of the `TextBox` as it is drawn on the screen. So your binding becomes:

```
<TextBox FontSize="{Binding Path=ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource HeightToFontSizeConverter}}" Text="12345" />
```

Notice that I used a converter because the ratio `Height` to `FontSize` is not 1:1 and the text is too big for the `TextBox`:

```
class HeightToFontSizeConverter : IValueConverter {

  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
    var height = (double) value;
    return .65 * height;
  }

  public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
    throw new NotImplementedException();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

A simple Viewbox could do the trick, but there are issues.

Refer to this reply.. [How to relative scale size of User Control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417004/how-to-relative-scale-size-of-user-control/1417342#1417342)

I'm in favour of the converter approach as in Julien's reply.

Answer (score 0):

I just did a quick test. If I bind the `Text` property of a `TextBox` to the `Width` of the containing grid the result is `NaN`. That would probably be the reason your binding fails.

If I instead bind the `FontSize` property of the `TextBox` to the `ActualWidth` property the binding is OK, and also resizes with the grid. The font is huge though. You would probably need some converter to make the `FontSize` smaller.

```
  <Grid x:Name="myGrid">
      <TextBox Text="Hello" FontSize="{Binding ElementName=myGrid, Path=ActualWidth}"/>
  </Grid>
```