# resize fontsize in Textbox automatically

Tags: c#, wpf, fonts, textbox

I have `Textbox`es in a `Grid` with numbers in it. If I resize the window, I want to change the `FontSize` too.

This code works with the actual height of the `TextBox`:

```
<TextBox FontSize="{Binding Path=ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
         Converter={StaticResource HeightToFontSizeConverter}}" Text="12345"/>
```

But now the `FontSize` only resizes in one direction.

Is there a possibility to bind two paths? Or another option?

Thank you.

Comment: "But the Fontsize only resizes in one direction."  Please clarify which direction.

Answer (score 3):

If you want scalable TextBox, or any other control, wrap it in to ViewBox. It defines a content decorator that can stretch and scale a single child to fill the available space.

Like:

```
<Viewbox>
  <Button>Button</Button>
</Viewbox>
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

A two binding in your case would be that setting the FontSize would affect the Height of the TextBox. But that my friend, ain't gonna happen! ActualHeight is a read only property.

```
public double ActualHeight { get; }
```

Also, do take a look at this reply.

[How to relative scale size of User Control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417004/how-to-relative-scale-size-of-user-control/1417342#1417342)